# htaccess rewriting with 3 subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url like this in my website.

```
http://localhost/tutor_institute/profiles/tutors/index.php?tutorCode=1255&tutorName=Jhon Amarathunga&city=Perth
```

I need to rewrite it something like this

```
http://localhost/tutor_institute/profiles/tutors/1255/Perth/Jhon Amarathunga.html
```

here tutor_insitute, profiles and tutors are sub directories in my root directory. index.php page exist in tutors directory and also my htaccess file placed there.

I did in my htaccess file like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/tutor_institute/profiles/tutors/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z_]+)/([A-Za-z_]+)$ index.php?tutorCode=$1&tutorName=$2&city=$3 [NC]
```

but it is not working.. anybody tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: "It is not working" isn't very helpful. What is the current behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried it without the very first forward slash?

Comment: Turn on [RewriteLog](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and try to find info there or post it here.

Comment: I just tried it without that forward slash. But result is still same. that mean my url is not changing as I expect.

Comment: Okay, so please help us to help you by using Jonas's suggestion or telling us what behaviour you are seeing

Comment: current behavior is not changing my browser URL. It is like this http://localhost/tutor_institute/profiles/tutors/index.php?tutorCode=1255&tutorName=Kasun%20Perera&city=Perth

Comment: in apache error.log file there are two many list and I got this line from it's last line. [Thu Jun 14 22:50:30 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/tutor_institute/profiles/tutors/images/telephone.gif, referer: http://localhost/tutor_institute/profiles/tutors/styles/tutor.css